# protractor executeScript weirdness with ElementArrayFinder

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, pageobjects, end-to-end

I have this declared in my Page Object:

```
this.paginationPageNumberList = element.all(by.repeater("page in pages track by $index"));
```

Running this inside a function of Page Object, its successful and prints 'no wrap':

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(254,1600);');
this.paginationPageNumberList.get(0).then(function() {
    console.log("no wrap");
});
```

Running the same thing except with a `then()` gives me an error:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(254,1600);').then(function () {
    this.paginationPageNumberList.get(0).then(function() {
        console.log("wrap");
    });
});
```

> Failed: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid *`this` in this case is not referring to the page object*.

Instead, make a separate variable:

```
var paginationPageNumberList = element.all(by.repeater("page in pages track by $index"));
this.paginationPageNumberList = paginationPageNumberList;

browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(254,1600);').then(function () {
    paginationPageNumberList.get(0).then(function() {
        console.log("wrap");
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but whats the explanation on why wrapping makes it not refer to the page object?

Comment: @awaken I think the current execution context is not the page object in this case, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work.